# Talking about a student who has been in exams

Tags: grammaticality

If a student has been appearing in exams for the last three days, what do we have to say?

> He has been taking exams for the last three days.

Or something else?

Comment: Sounds okay to me.

Comment: Can it be "He has been giving exams for the last three days"

Comment: If i am a teacher taking his exam then what to say in the same senario:"I have been taking his exams for the last three days"

Comment: @aliya - not without changing the meaning, giving exams implies he was invigilating (giving the exam to others).

Comment: Can i have few examples for "giving exams"Vs "taking exams "

Comment: Teachers have been giving me exams all week.  I have been taking exams all week.  I hope I pass them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is fine, but you could also say:

> He's had exams for the past three days.